# nose puede poner otro color a mi texto de gridview aspnet

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

que tal estoy realizando una gridview tratando de cambiar el color de mi tabla la cuestion es que tengo la siguiente tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es que ese color que ese texto que apunta sea de color blanco para que se distingan las letras aqui pongo mi codigo

```
<ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" PageSize="7"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="10" DataSourceID="SUCOMHIS" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                           <asp:BoundField DataField="ADESTINO"  HeaderText="Destinos" SortExpression="ADESTINO" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ACLASESERVICIO" HeaderText="Tipo de Servicio" SortExpression="ACLASESERVICIO" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NTARIFA" HeaderText="Precio" SortExpression="NTARIFA" DataFormatString="{0:F2}" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="HHORASALIDAVIAJE" HeaderText="Horario" SortExpression="HHORASALIDAVIAJE" >
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#004B93"  Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="red" />
                        
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="white" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="black" />
                        
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="white" ForeColor="#0D93D2" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Font-Size="X-Small" />
                        
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#003565" ForeColor="black" Font-Size="45px" />
                        
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#003AB8"  Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 estilos paras las filas:

- `RowStyle`
- [AlternatingRowStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.alternatingrowstyle?view=netframework-4.8)

Las cuales se van intercalando, para dar el efecto "zebra". Ambos tienen la propiedades

- `BackColor`: Color de fondo
- `ForeColor`: Color del texto

```
<ContentTemplate>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" PageSize="7"  runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="10" DataSourceID="SUCOMHIS" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
     <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="black" />
     <RowStyle BackColor="#003565" ForeColor="White" Font-Size="45px" />

//El resto del Grid
// OJO con NO repetir las 2 propiedades a arriba!!!!
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias

Comment: @RobertMendoza Me alegro, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si así te parece